# SQL unionall, null

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have the first table and need to convert it to the second one. That is the maker should appear only for the first row and replaced by NULL in its later occurrences.

```
MAKER   TYPE        RNK
A       PC          1
A       Laptop      2
A       Printer     3
B       PC          1
B       Laptop      2
C       Laptop      1
D       Printer     1
E       PC          1
E       Printer     2


MAKER   TYPE      RNK
A       PC         1  
NULL    Laptop     2 
NULL    Printer    3
B       PC         1
NULL    Laptop     2 
C       Laptop     1
D       Printer    1
E       PC         1
NULL    Printer    2
```

I tried with

```
select maker, type, rnk from a1 where rnk = 1
union all
select '', type, rnk from a1 where rnk = 2 
union all
select '', type, rnk  from a1 where rnk = 3
```

But this does not preserve the order, for all the nulls get grouped together by default like this

```
A       PC         1        
B       PC         1     
C       Laptop     1     
D       Printer    1      
E       PC         1      
NULL    Laptop     2      
NULL    Printer    3      
NULL    Laptop     2       
NULL    Printer    2
```

Comment: You should _not_ be doing this in the data layer.  Changing the data to `null` completely disassociates the changed records with the original maker value.  If you want to avoid showing duplicate `maker` values then do that in the _display_ layer (report, app, whatever). Do _not_ change your data to get it to _display_ properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree about doing this sort of thing outside of sql, but it can be done simply with a `CASE` expression and an `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN rnk = 1 THEN MAKER ELSE '' END AS Mkr, type, rnk 
FROM Table1
ORDER BY MAKER,RNK
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5df54/5/0)

Comment: Correction: I am using the sql-ex.com website, perhaps this is ordering is a fault with them. <yes i tried that, but the order by doesn't work as oracle bunches all the rows with null maker together by default>

Comment: If you alias the `CASE` expression with the same name as the field, it will order by the `CASE` expression output, hence using `Mkr` for that field and using `MAKER` in the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

## This kind of operation should be done in presentation layer!

It looks to me you want something like merging cells in raport. DB is not appropriate place to do this kind of operations.

[image]
[image]

But if you insist you can use sth like:

```
WITH cte AS (
 SELECT *, i = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Maker)
  FROM tab
)
select maker, type, rnk,i from cte a1 where rnk = 1
union all
select '', type, rnk,i from  cte a1 where rnk = 2 
union all
select '', type, rnk,i  from cte a1 where rnk = 3
ORDER BY i, rnk;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/393234)**</kbd>

or using simple `CASE`:

```
WITH cte AS(
  select maker, type, rnk from tab a1 where rnk = 1
  union all
  select maker, type, rnk from tab a1 where rnk = 2 
  union all
  select maker, type, rnk from tab a1 where rnk = 3
)
SELECT CASE WHEN rnk <> 1 THEN '' ELSE maker END AS maker_name,
     type,
     rnk
FROM cte
ORDER BY maker, rnk;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/393253)**</kbd>